# How to use an R-Tree for knnsearch in Matlab

Tags: matlab, kdtree, r-tree

how to convert a kd-tree to a r-tree for using in knnsearch?

```
KDTreeMdl = KDTreeSearcher(X,'Distance','minkowski','P',5)
[IdxMk,DMk] = knnsearch(KDTreeMdl,newpoint,'k',10);
```

Comment: In order to get help, please proide more details on what you have tried and where you are stuck. I'll give a very short answer because I have no more details: KD-Trees and R-Trees are fundamentally different. The only way I can think of is to read all entries from the kd-tree and put them into an R-Tree.

Comment: I am trying to change matlab knnsearch code to work with R*tree or R-Tree instead of KD-Tree. I read somewhere that knnsearch works on R-Tree already, if that is true, I have to change it to R*-tree and I am done. thanks.

Comment: Please add any additional information to the question so others can easily find it.
I also suggest to change the title of your question (or create a new question) to something like "How to use an R-Tree for knnsearch in Matlab" or similar. I do not know how to use an R-Tree for knnsearch in Matlab.

Comment: I did that, thank you.